# How can I run these 2 python routines at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, parallel-processing

How can I run these 2 python routines at the same time?

first routine

```
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
try:
    ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_data(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
    ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Stock Prices\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
```

and run this one at the same time

second routine

```
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
try:
    ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_income_statement(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
    ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Income Statement\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
```

Comment: As of now, a valid answer could be *"open two terminals and launch python twice"*... Which is maybe what you were looking for, but I doubt it. I'm pretty sure your question needs some more refining before you get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this would be with the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) package included with the standard library. Wrapping your two blocks in functions, and then wrapping them in threads should do the job -- i.e.

```
def write_prices():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_data(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Stock Prices\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

def write_incomes():                
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_income_statement(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Income Statement\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

import threading

# construct the threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=write_prices)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=write_incomes)

# start the threads
[t.start() for t in (t1, t2)]

# wait until they finish
[t.join() for t in (t1, t2)]
```

This should work, though if you have shared values between `get_data(...)` and `get_income_statement(...)` you could hit some kind of issue that would need to be solved with locks.

Comment: looks like this works, thx. Can I modify it and add other def to it? I would like to not 2 but a total of 5 loops working all at the same time. Thx

Comment: You can follow the pattern of `threading.Thread(target=your_function).start()` with as many threads as you like. Performance will start to deteriorate once you hit the number of cores on your computer. You can check [here](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/) for more detailed information about multi-threaded programming in Python.